# Close listening socket in python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem trying to learn about sockets for network communication. I have made a simple thread that listens for connections and creates processes for connecting clients, my problem though is that I can't get the thread to join properly as I haven't found a way to cancel the socket.accept()-call when I want to quit the program.

My code looks like this;

```
class ServerThread( threading.Thread ):

    def __init__(self, queue, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.running = True
        self.hostname = host
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.hostname, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(1)
        while self.running:
            try:
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()
                process = Process(target=server_slave, args=(conn, address, self.queue))
                process.daemon = True
                process.start()
            except socket.timeout:
                pass

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.socket.close()
```

I have managed to get the program to close by setting `self.setDaemon(True)` and just exiting the main program, handing everything to the great garbage collector - but that seems like a bad solution. I've also tried setting a timeout for the socket but that results in getting `[Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable` (regardless of the actual timeout, even when I set it to years...).

What am I doing wrong? Have I designed the thread in a dumb way or have I missed something about accepting connections?

Comment: 'but that seems like a bad solution' - does it work?  If you don't like having the OS terminate all your threads, you could try closing the listening socket from the main, or other, thread.  That usually causes the accept() to return 'early' with an error.  Works on most OS/languages, but not tried with Python, so not an answer.

Comment: It works - but I get the feeling I might not be treating potential clients very well in doing that. I posted a solution that seems nicer as it allows the code to complete, but it still seems a bit odd since it ends by creating a new process that I'll have to join right away.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way to get the thread to close seems to be to make a connection to the socket, thus continuing the thread to completion.

```
def stop(self):
    self.running = False
    socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect( (self.hostname, self.port))
    self.socket.close()
```

This works, but it still feels like it might not be optimal...

Comment: Yes - 'artificially' satisfying the wait condition, (as here- opening a temporary local connection), is also in the 'stop blocked thread' bag of tricks.

Comment: You seem to know this stuff! ^^
Thanks for the help! Any other tricks I might try?

Comment: Currently trying to understand this issue / code - I would have done the same but I cannot get my head around the "socket,.socket(socket.AF_INET...) line - what is its purpose?

Comment: Kev1n91, the `socket.socket( [...] ).connect( [...] )` line basically creates a temporary socket object, where AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM is the address family and socket type. This is used to create a connection to the process that is waiting for a connection, so that it can be told to stop waiting! Just telling it to close wouldn't work as it's set to wait forever for a connection before taking new instructions.

Answer (score 3):

A dirty solution which allows to exit your program is to use `os._exit(0)`.

```
def stop(self):
    self.socket.close()
    os._exit(0)
```

note that `sys.exit` doesn't work/blocks as it tries to exit cleanly/release resources. But `os._exit` is the most low level way and it works, when nothing else does.

The operating system itself will release the resources (on any modern system) like when doing `exit` in a C program.

Comment: Yuuup, personally happy with this one, brute force is always an option :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you will open a new thread or process once a connection is accepted. To close the connection, break the while loop. Garbage collection will remove the thread or process but join will ensure none get left behind.

Persistent sockets close when the user closes them or they timeout. Non-persistent, like static webpages will close after they've sent the information.

Here's a good example of a persistent socket server in Python. It uses multiprocessing which means it can run across multiple cores for CPU-bound tasks. More commonly known as multithreading.

```
import socket
import multiprocessing

def run():
    host = '000.000.000.000'
    port = 1212
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', port))
    sock.listen(3)
    while True:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=sock.accept()).start()
def worker(conn, addr):
    while True:
        if data == '':
            #remote connection closed
            break
         if len(dataList) > 2:
            # do stuff
            print 'This code is untested'

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have a single listening thread that has nothing to do with your connection threads and give it a reasonable length timeout. On timeout, check if this thread should shutdown and if not, loop again and go back to listening.

```py
    def tcp_listen_handle(self, port=23, connects=5, timeout=2):
        """This is running in its own thread."""
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.settimeout(timeout)
        sock.bind(('', port))
        sock.listen(connects)  # We accept more than one connection.
        while self.keep_running_the_listening_thread():
            connection = None
            addr = None
            try:
                connection, addr = sock.accept()
                print("Socket Connected: %s" % str(addr))
                # makes a thread deals with that stuff. We only do listening.
                self.handle_tcp_connection_in_another_thread(connection, addr)
            except socket.timeout:
                pass
            except OSError:
                # Some other error.
                print("Socket was killed: %s" % str(addr))
                if connection is not None:
                    connection.close()
        sock.close()
```

The only thing this does is listen, timeout, checks if it should die during the timeout, and goes back to listening. The general rule of thumb is that threads should check whether they should die and try to do that themselves as fast as they can. And if you don't want to take the 2 second hit for timeout wait before the thread unblocks and checks. You can connect to it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Partially tested solution

1. Put `self.socket.settimeout(0.1)` right before `while`
2. Put `conn.settimeout(None)` right after `accept`

Comment: Following this advice was by far the worst decision I've made all day

Comment: I found `settimeout()` to work for me, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41643863/143931.

Comment: Paradoxis, can you expand (I know, 3.5 years later) on why it was a bad decision?  I can imagine it fails in all sorts of fun ways but was hoping to avoid learning those myself.