# KeyboardInterrupt is not throwing the except clause when CRTL+C is pressed

Tags: python, server, try-catch, except, keyboardinterrupt

I am implementing a socket server in python. Everything works well except KeyboardInterrupt does not stop my server in the terminal. Any ideas? Thank a lot!

```
    def run(self) -> None:
        try:
            self.socket.listen()
            print(f'$ - Server {self.host}:{self.port} is running.')
            while True:
                client, address = self.socket.accept()
                Thread(target=clientHandler, args=[client, address]).start()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('! - Server interrupted.')
```

when `ctrl+c` is pressed it should stop the server but it does not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't close socket on KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871191/cant-close-socket-on-keyboardinterrupt)

Comment: No, that's a different question. The problem there is that the `try except ` clause is inside the `while True` loop. mine is not. But thank you

Comment: The underlying problem is that is `socket.accept` is blocking. Having it timeout occasionally _should_ allow you to `KeyboardInterrupt`. Where the `try`/`except` block is, doesn't really matter in this case. All you need is to set something like `self.socket.settimeout(.5)` and handle the timeout in a `try`,`except socket.timeout: pass` within your `while` loop.