# Proper way to use KeyboardInterrupt with UDP socket.recv()?

Tags: python, sockets, signals

I'm currently using `socket.socketpair()` with `signal.set_wakeup_fd()` as a solution to make `socket.recv()` compatible with `KeyboardInterrupt` on Windows — particularly when using UDP — see below for example.

I'm also aware of the [other popular solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34871191/1874170) of configuring a busy loop with `timeout=` to periodically check if the program's been interrupted.

Both of these solutions seem like pretty **ugly hacks**, though. Is there any "correct" way to do this?

---

```py
import select
import signal
import socket

def _udp_listen(address, family=socket.AF_INET, flags=0, sockopts=frozenset()):
    bufsize = getpagesize()
    with socket.socket(family, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        for sockopt in sockopts:
            sock.setsockopt(*sockopt)
        sock.bind(address)
        _coalmine, _canary = socket.socketpair()
        with _canary, _coalmine, _wakeup_fd_ctx(_coalmine.fileno(), strict=True, warn_on_full_buffer=False):
            while True:
                ready = select.select((sock, _canary), (), ())[0]
                if _canary in ready:
                    # There's no need to raise any error ourselves,
                    # since Python itself will raise KeyboardInterrupt
                    # out of select.select() if needed
                    pass
                if sock in ready:
                    yield sock.recv(bufsize, flags)


# -----

from contextlib import contextmanager

try:
    from resource import getpagesize
except ImportError:
    import mmap
    def getpagesize():
        return mmap.PAGESIZE


@contextmanager
def _wakeup_fd_ctx(fd, strict=True, **k):
    _orig_wakeup_fd = signal.set_wakeup_fd(fd, **k)
    _needs_restore = True
    try:
        if _orig_wakeup_fd == -1:
            yield fd
        else:
            # We overwrote the existing handler
            if strict:
                raise RuntimeError(f'wakeup fd already occupied ({_orig_wakeup_fd}). Not sure what to do about that.')
            else:
                signal.set_wakeup_fd(_orig_wakeup_fd)
                _needs_restore = False
                yield _orig_wakeup_fd
    finally:
        if _needs_restore:
            signal.set_wakeup_fd(_orig_wakeup_fd)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible with KeyboardInterrupt"? How is it incompatible? If you type Ctl-c, it should break out of `socket.recv()`. If you're inside a `try` block, it will go to the matching `except` block.

Comment: @Barmar That's simply not the case, as you can easily test. If you press `Ctrl` `C` while `socket.recv()` is running, nothing will happen \(except that, *later*, when a timeout is hit or data is received, the exception will be raised.\) This is a very well known struggle, as you can tell by clicking the first link in my answer to check out another popular solution, or by simply Googling “python ctrl c not working socket.recv”.

Comment: Are you on Windows? According to comments at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871253/1491895) it works on Unix, but not Windows. There are some other solutions (including timeouts) at that question.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm on Windows. I'll test it on Linux when I get home, and if this behavior is Windows-specific I'll edit the question to note that.

Comment: @Barmar You claim the other thread has "other solutions", but falsetru, Hansimov, Rolf of Saxony, GratefulGuest, and betontalpfa all prescribe putting a timeout on `conn.recv()` in a busy while loop; JacobIRR gives a broken fragment of an Object-Oriented socket server daemon that's missing the crucial line of code; Uddhav Bhosle also prescribes a timeout — so I'm not clear what you're trying to bring to my attention given that I already linked that thread in my OP. The timeout solution seems kludgy, but my wakeup_fd solution seems overengineered. I'm wondering if there's a **proper** solution.

Comment: It may be kludgey, but sometimes kludges are the best way to work around problems. From what I could tell when I researched, it seems like the most common method.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following of any help? The basic paradigm is to put your read sockets to a list, then do a select and then check which socket has data available and then act on the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import socket
import select
import threading


glob_control_read_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
glob_control_read_socket.bind(('localhost', 0))

glob_control_write_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
glob_control_write_socket.connect(('localhost', glob_control_read_socket.getsockname()[1]))

glob_server_read_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
glob_server_read_socket.bind(('localhost', 12000))

print("Server running on port " + str(glob_server_read_socket.getsockname()[1]))

def sockets_shutdown():
    glob_control_write_socket.close()
    glob_control_read_socket.close()
    glob_server_read_socket.close()
    print("Graceful shutdown")

def handle_server_read():
    read_str = glob_server_read_socket.recv(100).decode("utf-8")
    print("Server got: " + read_str.rstrip())
    
def sockets_thread_main():

    read_sockets_list = [glob_control_read_socket, glob_server_read_socket]
    while True:
        try:
            read_sockets,_,_ = select.select(read_sockets_list, [], [])
            for ready_socket in read_sockets:
                if ready_socket == glob_control_read_socket:
                    control_bytes = glob_control_read_socket.recv(32)
                    if control_bytes == b"QUIT":
                        sockets_shutdown()
                        return
                if ready_socket == glob_server_read_socket:
                    handle_server_read()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

sockets_thread = threading.Thread(target = sockets_thread_main, args = ())

try:
    sockets_thread.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(100000) # Placeholder, do something real here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    glob_control_write_socket.send(b"QUIT")
    sockets_thread.join()
```

Tested on recent Windows 10 and ncat (funnily, if I connect with ncat to localhost, it is unable to make the connection and reports "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." I need to use 127.0.0.1)

Test run:
[image: Test run]

EDIT: Is socketpair() even available in Windows?

Comment: Indeed, socketpair() is available on Windows, and works with `select.select()` *and* `SOCK_DGRAM`

Comment: The idea of using a control socket to communicate with the UDP client which is on a separate thread is a good one. However, if I put the socket on a separate thread, that introduces the challenge of streaming data over to the main thread...