# Python How to close a socket instantiated in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I have a multithreaded program which instantiates 5 Socket Objects as Follows:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, pid, port_num, restart):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.hostname = '127.0.0.1'
        self.pid = pid
        self.port_num = port_num
        self.ID = pid
        self.restart = restart
        self.delay = pid*4*1000

    def run(self):
        try:
            s = timer(self.hostname, self.port_num, self.pid)
            #print "Socket S run"+str(s)
            sendToSocket(self.pid, s, self.t, self.ID)
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

Here the function `timer` is used to Instantiate a thread in the Following manner:

```
def timer(host, port, pid):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)      
    timed = pid * 4 * 100
    s.settimeout(timed)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    return s
```

I Want to terminate one of the sockets at a particular port say 5005.
The pid in the above example goes from 5001 to 5005.

***I Want to shut down a socket in between - say 5005*.**

So I used this method:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5005))
s.close()
```

But the Socket doesn't close. 
I need to call the above procedure from an external function.

In short, if there is a socket bound to port 5005, I want to close the socket and make it unavailable so that we'd get a `Port not found exception.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close listening socket in python thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734534/close-listening-socket-in-python-thread)

Comment: As your`class myThread ` hold the `.port_num`, does `myThread_instance.s.close()` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a dictionary with port as key and socket as value .

```
my_sockets = {}
```

Then add all your new sockets in that dictionary in the `run` or `timer` function .

```
def timer(host, port, pid):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)      
    timed = pid * 4 * 100
    s.settimeout(timed)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    my_sockets[port] = s  
    return s
```

Finally make a function to close and remove sockets from that dictionary .

```
def close_socket(port):
    if port in my_sockets : 
        my_sockets[port].close()
        my_sockets.pop(port)
```