# How can I have a spinner while waiting for socket.accept?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a spinner right here:

```
spinner = itertools.cycle(['-', '/', '|', '\\'])
while True:
    sys.stdout.write(spinner.next())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I'm stuck at my code

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((target,port))
server.listen(10)
print "Waiting for a client!"
client, addr = server.accept()
```

I don't know where or what condition I must use but I know how to implement a spinner. I want my `"Waiting for a client"` to make it clear for the user that it is waiting. I thought of a spinner.

Comment: Is it the `accept` function on the next line that may take some time? Since it appears to not have an "I'm waiting" callback, you need a separate thread to do anything while it's working.

Comment: Yes. I'm going to try threading, maybe I can get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You should set a timeout before calling `accept()` in a loop.  See here: [python socket object accept time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354476/python-socket-object-accept-time-out) for details on how, but the idea is to try to accept a new connection for say 0.1 seconds, then bump the spinner, then repeat.