# Workaround for exiting threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to write a server program and I have a thread for listening for new clients:

```
class ClientFinder(Thread):
    def __init__(self, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._continue = True
        self._port = port
        # try to create socket

    def run(self):
        # listen for new clients
        while self._continue:
            # add new clients

    def stop(self):
        # stop client
        self._continue = False

client_finder = ClientFinder(8000)
client_finder.start()
client_finder.stop()
client_finder.join()
```

I can't join client_finder because it never ends. Calling stop() lets the thread stop *after* the next client is accepted, so the program just hangs forever.

1) Is it okay for my program to just end even if I haven't joined all my threads (such as by removing the join)? Or is this lazy/bad practice?

2) If it is a problem, what's the solution/best practice to avoid this? From what I've found so far, there's no way to force a thread to stop.

Comment: You have to join before calling stop

Comment: I changed the order and that did not solve my problem. (Program doesn't end.)

Comment: If you're not joining the threads, how do you know the program is finished?

Comment: In my real code, I have a print("Done!") after everything else and the IDLE will print a new line with the ">>>"

Answer (score 0):

Whether waiting for the current clients to finish is a problem is really your choice. It may be a good idea, or you may prefer to kill connections.

Waiting for a new client is probably a worse thing, since it may never happen. An easy solution would be to have some reasonable timeout for the listening - let's say if nobody connects in 5s, you go back to the loop to check the flag. This is short enough for a typical shutdown solution, but long enough that rechecking shouldn't affect your CPU usage.

If you don't want to wait for a short timeout, you can add a pipe/socket between the thread doing shutdown and your `ClientFinder` and send a notification to shutdown. Instead of only waiting for a new client, you'd need to wait on both fds (I'm assuming `ClientFinder` uses sockets) and check which of them got a message.

Comment: 1) How do I add a timeout? I don't think socket.accept() takes any arguments and if the thread is still waiting on accept(), how do I get it to stop with a timeout?
2) What's fds in this context?

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354476/python-socket-object-accept-time-out 2) file descriptors