# Change a python server to client after a specific timeout

Tags: python, client-server

So, I have a server socket defined as `server_sock` the current code looks as follow

```
# define a variable server_sock
server_sock.bind(("", PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]
client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("[+] Accepted connection from ", client_info)
server_sock.close()
client_sock.close()
# define a variable sock 
sock.connect((host, port))   # This will be the client socket
```

Now, this code will create a `server_sock` , listen for incoming connections and after any client is connected it will close those socket and act as client by using another `sock`.

What I am planning to do is to first let the code run as a server (i.e `server_sock` should wait for connections) for specific timeout (Let's assume 10 seconds).

After the 10 seconds, the `server_sock` should get closed by itself and then the next piece of code (i.e client part) should start.

So, it's loosely something like change from Server Mode to Client Mode after a specific Time-Out.

I am having a hard time to solve this issue. Usually `server_sock.accept()` line would be stuck until it hits a new connection else it won't proceed.

So, how can I implement something which breaks that whole thing after a specific time-out.

Note that I am running this code cross platform on Windows and UNIX. So, I have been looking to some `signal` specific answers but Windows doesn't support some Signal.

EDIT:

Many people are saying to use `settimeout()` on the socket. But that doesn't answer the behavior I need.

Because Let's say if I get a connection from a device during the server_sock mode, I would *like* to continue communication thereafter rather than abruptly closing the socket.

The settimeout() will close socket no matter what actions are being performed. So, that fails to answer my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python socket object accept time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354476/python-socket-object-accept-time-out)

Comment: That also doesn't seem to be like the answer @GabrielPellegrino . Because let's say if a device connects during my server mode, then I will like to continue the connection with that device rather than breaking it.

Comment: If you accepted a request, you can change the timeout or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a **timeout** function.

```
# define a socket variable server_sock

server_sock.settimeout(10.0)  #setting timeout for 10 sec

# rest of your code
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question . Because let's say if a device connects during my server mode, then I will like to continue the connection with that device rather than breaking it.