# How to end threads after a specified amount of time?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have this python script that just starts up threads to listen on some ports on the localhost.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import threading
import concurrent.futures

threads = []

def listen_on_port(port):
    HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = int(port)          # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr,conn)


def main(ports):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for port in ports:
            executor.submit(listen_on_port,port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(ports=[50010,50020,50030])
```

When I run this script it listens on the ports as expected.  I use this script to test that the firewall rules are allowing connections on those ports.  And on another system I execute `nc -zv my-host 50010` and the thread is listening on port 50010 terminates, which is what I want.

But, I would like to make two improvements: 1) have the threads die after X seconds, 2) Run the threads in the back ground like daemons so that my script will exit and leave the threads running.

I have been trying to figure this out for days and I have gotten no where.  Please help!

Comment: 1) You can add a timeout to a socket like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354476/python-socket-object-accept-time-out 2) You can make a script that stays running in the background using this package https://daemonize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: WIth Daemonize, how does one pass parameters to the function specified in the `action` parameter?

Comment: You can construct an object with the parameters you need, and define the function as a method on that object, or you can use functools.bind().

Comment: @NickODell I took your advice on how to use daemonize but that has lead toa new question.  Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71418945/why-cant-i-start-more-than-on-daemon-with-daemonize